# Why is my Sturmey-Archer 5-speed hub sticking between 1st and 2nd gear?

Tags: internally-geared-hub, sturmey-archer

I've been trying to set up a Sturmey-Archer X-RD5 (W) hub to no avail. I can get it moving between 2nd and 5th gears just fine, but as soon as I pull it into 1st the indicator rod (and I assume internal clutch) sticks in an awkward position and won't go back inside (and therefore back down to 2nd gear) smoothly/without persuasion. I've disassembled the hub and put it back together (correctly), cleaning old grease out and relubricating it.
The indicator rod has a yellow paint mark which helps with alignment, I wondered do different lengths come with different colours?
It's using a Sturmey-Archer SL-S50 thumb shifter which I've checked is compatible with the hub (and regardless, the problem is happening when I pull the rod with my hands disconnected from the cable).
This is really frustrating me and my colleagues! Has anybody experienced this problem before?